# How to use own defconfig for linux in yocto meta layer

Tags: linux, yocto

I created a meta layer for Yocto, and I am able to download Linux and apply patches to it.

In my own meta layer, when I place `defconfig` file in the meta layer, it is added to the Linux default config.

How can I make Linux use the config from my meta layer only?

Comment: Do you have a machine configuration file which you call with the setup of the enviroment?

Comment: Why don't you patch the existing config file, is it entirely different?

Comment: I do not really understand your question.  Please add more details on what you are doing and what is the behavior from yocto.

Comment: Sorry, initially i thought my defconfig gets appended to kernel .config, but the defconfig inside reciepes-kernel/linux/files/defconfig is the one kernel is taking. Problem solved